# Converting Linear Layout UI to Relative Layout

Tags: android

Can i Convert this Linear Layout view into Relative Layout view with proper weight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/favButton2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gotoButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/favButton4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:background="@drawable/appback" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:background="@drawable/appback" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favSms"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextFavSms"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PreFavSms"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Pre" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

this is the o/p which i am getting from the above linear layout i want the same using relative layout that support all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Relative Layout you can't use weight but you can achieve this design can you make your question clear. What your finding difficult in designing this layout? Relative layout would be better if you go for different screen size

Comment: Actually when I am making my parent layout as Relative, because of weight everything become vanish so how can I manage my weight with relative layout to achieve this UI.

Comment: If you make the parent layout as Relative means you have specify the child layout properly in case linear layout you specify the orientation but according to RelativeLayout you need to specify the properties properly